# I have one form and my label is not in the same line of text area

Tags: php, html, label

```html
 
<tr> 
  <td valign="top" width="25%" class="contact-form" id="require">Or please give us a description of your requirements (Max:1000 characters)<font color="red" size="3">*</font>
  </td> 
  <td width="5%" class="contact-form">:</td>
  <td width="70%" class="contact-text-form"><textarea name="requirements" class="contact-form-filds2" id="requirements" cols="1000" rows="3" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($require);?>" ></textarea><span class="error"><?php echo $requireErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
```

Or please give us a description of your requirements (Max:1000 characters)*
    
   : 
   " >

Comment: Don't put that as a comment, place it in your question and format it properly. Are you asking a question on html or php or what? Give a more specific tag.

Comment: html form in php file

Comment: please change the question content, add code and explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it in the table's `<tr></tr>` element to align it properly without the `valign` attribute. Each label, textfield has only one row to display it properly.

Answer (score 0):

in your css stylesheet, just add:

```
textarea {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```